# Using Scope Identity for multiple inserts within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use scope identity twice within a stored procedure.

My stored procedure has 3 elements,

- 1st an insert into a table (I use the scope identity here to get the
  newly inserted row ID)
- 2nd an insert to the 2nd table, this inserts the ID from the 1st
  insert, I also use the scope identity to get the id of this new row
- 3rd an update to the 1st table with the 2nd table new ID

The first table ID works fine although I do not seem to be able to get the ID from the 2nd table and then update the 1st with that ID.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post your current stored proc code?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it this way

```
insert t1 values (...) -- first insert

declare @id1 as int = scope_identity() -- store the first id

insert t2 values (@id1, ...) -- second insert

update t1
set id2 = scope_identity() -- id from the second table
where id1 = @id1 -- primary key of the first table
```

Answer (score -1):

Use querys something like this

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([Id1] ,[Name],[DateCreated]) 
VALUES (@RId, @Name, GetDate())

DECLARE @NewId1 INT=0  -- recently inserted id in Table-1
SET @NewId1  = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)

INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Id2],[Id1],[Name],[DateCreated]) 
VALUES (@RId, @NewId1, @Name, GetDate())  -- insert the newly created Table-1 id into Table-2

DECLARE @NewId2 INT=0 -- recently inserted id in Table-2
SET @NewId2  = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)

INSERT INTO [Table3] ([Id3],[Id2],[Name],[DateCreated]) 
VALUES (@RId, @NewId2, @Name, GetDate())  -- insert the newly created Table-2 id into Table-3
```